# Re-using a key in systemd unit

Tags: systemd

My sysd unit is something like

```
[Unit]
Description=%p
....
[Service]
Type=notify
....
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '\
/usr/libexec/sdnotify-proxy /run/%p.sock \
....-s LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG \'    
WatchdogSec=2
```

How can I re-use `WatchdogSec` key in `exec-start`, rather than duplicating the value `2`?

Comment: The only way i see here is to use the Environment option like this: Environment=INT_VALUE=2 You can acces it by $INT_VALUE